# Problem when copying and pasting codes

Tags: dataset, image, copy-as

When I copy codes I usually have problems, because when I paste them to the Mathematica notebook, they don't run as they should. It has happened to me already several times, and specifically now when I copied a code from a book and pasted it into the notebook. It should run the dataset but it shows this strange output. Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Maybe 'Copy As > Plain Text' would work.

Comment: There is no way we can help you from a screenshot, but it seems likely that some sort of formatting is getting in the way. Try copying from your source, then pasting into a text editor like notepad, then copying from there and pasting into Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks friends, I could not solve the problem. I had to rewrite letter by letter all the code. It's complicated, but that's what I have.